# Proving the summation - $f_{2n-1} (\frac{k\pi}{2n}) \rightarrow \frac{2}{\pi} \int_{0}^{k\pi} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} dx, k =1,2,3,..$

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

Let $f_{2n-1}(x) = \frac{4}{\pi} [\sin(x) + \frac{1}{3} \sin(3x) + ... + \frac{1}{(2n-1)} \sin(2n-1)x]$.

How can I show $f_{2n-1} (\frac{k\pi}{2n}) \rightarrow \frac{2}{\pi} \int_{0}^{k\pi} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} dx, k =1,2,3,..$

I thought - 
$f_{2n-1}(\frac{k \pi}{2n}) = \frac{4}{\pi} [\sin(\frac{k \pi}{2n}) + \frac{1}{3}\sin(\frac{3k\pi}{2n}) +...+\frac{1}{2n-1} \sin(\frac{(2n-1)k\pi}{2n})]$.

But how to relate ?. I guess that the sum of the trigonometric functions must be reducing to a simple expression here?

I thought extending the sums to integration but that involves limit but here the terms are finite? how do I approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Differentiating $f_{2n-1}(x)$ wrt x gives you

$f'_{2n-1}(x)=\dfrac{4}{\pi}[cos(x)+cos(3x)+....+cos((2n-1)x)]=\dfrac{2}{\pi}\dfrac{sin(2nx)}{sin(x)}$

Integrating on both sides, you may get the required expression.

Comment: $f'_{2n-1}(\frac{k\pi}{2n}) = 0$

Comment: Also, $f_{2n-1}(x) = \int_{0}^{x} \frac{2 \sin(2nx)}{\pi \sin(x)} $ ?

Comment: $f_{2n-1}(x)=\dfrac{2}{\pi}\int _{0}^{x}\dfrac{sin(2nx)}{sin(x)}dx=\dfrac{1}{\pi n}\int _{0}^{2nx}\dfrac{sin(x)}{sin(\dfrac{x}{2n})}dx$.

$f_{2n-1}(\dfrac{k\pi}{2n}) = \dfrac{1}{\pi n}\int _{0}^{k\pi}\dfrac{sin(x)}{sin(\dfrac{x}{2n})}dx$.  I am not able to simplify further.

Comment: well I did, i got it thanks! $\frac{2}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\frac{t}{2n}} \frac{sin(x)}{sin(\frac{x}{2n})} d(\frac{x}{2n})$ now as $n \rightarrow \infty$ $\sin(\frac{x}{2n}) \rightarrow \frac{x}{2n}$ giving us $\frac{2}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\frac{t}{2n}} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} dx$ !! just we need to substitute now $t = k\pi$  :)

Comment: Ah yes. As $n$ tends to $\infty$, you'll get the required expression. Thanks.